# ActiveMQ keeps ESTABLISHED connections

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have an issue with one of my `AMQ` producers, I have networks issues with it, consequently it fails to send messages to the Q.
However, the server opens a connections to the Q machine and maintain them intact. The number of connections raises, the Q machine is suffocated and cannot serve the rest of its producers and consumers.

Here is the exception I catch in my "bad" producer:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1413)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1478)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:527)
    at com.queue.service.ActiveMQ.ActiveMQWriter.initSession(ActiveMQWriter.java:163)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1388)
    ... 7 more
```

Running `netstat` command on my "bad" producer gives me `State ESTABLISHED` for every failed request.

Running `netstat` command on my Q server gives me `State ESTABLISHED` from the "bad" producer, for every failed request.

**Question:** what parameter I need to modify in the producer and/or Q in order to "break" those connections after a configurable time?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use [failover transport](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html), so that your clients can try connecting again if the first attempt fails.

You can also try extending wire format negotiation period (default 10 sec).

You can do that by using wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay property on the connection URL in your client to increase to 30 sec timeout

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000)");
```

http://activemq.apache.org/javaxjmsjmsexception-wire-format-negociation-timeout-peer-did-not-send-his-wire-format.html

Comment: Can you post bad producer and AMQ logs entirely with time

Comment: the rest of the log is relevant, its my addings, what I posted is the AMQ log. it takes ~30 seconds to quit the sending, but the port stayed ESTABLISHED way longer